# Однородные члены

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая при перечислении?

У каждой группы свои условия работы (,) и свои проблемы, и свои пути решения проблем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, нужна. По правилам, если перечисление однородных членов начинается до первого из повторяющихся союзов, то запятая ставится уже перед первым из повторяющихся союзов.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Уже нашла это место у Розенталя.

Comment: Так примите ответ!